# Does gravity do work on suspended objects?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, work

A block is suspended from a string; does the gravitational force do any work on it?

Comment: Hi, Saffron, and welcome to Physics SE! Could you please provide some context to your question? Is the string moving? Is the block stationary or does it have velocity? Does it have acceleration? Does the string pull the block in the direction of motion?

Answer (score 2):

Work is performed when the point of application of a force travels through a distance in the direction of the force.

An object suspended by a string in a gravitational field experiences the force of gravity but if it does not move, then no work is being done on it.

Comment: Not really completely true. Friction does work opposite the direction of the force. You can have work in whatever direction if you consider many different forces.

Comment: I took the case where the work is positive.

Answer (score 1):

No, if the block is still, there is no work being done on it. There is a force on it, yes, but no work. Work is really a function of a period of time i.e. in 1 second, it did 1 Joule of work. It does not make sense to ask the value of such a quantity for any given moment.